# Powershell Script - Re-Prompt Password Screen If PW is İncorrect

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I have a script that will change all local administrator passwords with the below script. Script will prompt password for each server. (all servers have different passwords)
I want to re-prompt the credential screen if user enters wrong password but I couldn't handle it.

```
$servers = Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Scripts\TestServers.txt"

foreach($server in $servers)
{
    $pingtest = Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if($pingtest)
    {
        Write-Host($server + " is online")
        try
        {
            $ServerSessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential 'Administrator' 
            
        }catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]
        {
            Write-Host("Credential is incorrect! Try again")
            $ServerSessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential 'Administrator'
           
        }

            Invoke-Command -Session $ServerSessions -ScriptBlock {
                # Windows Server Versiyonunu check edip parolayı ona göre set etmek için
                Get-ComputerInfo | select WindowsProductName, WindowsVersion, OsHardwareAbstractionLayer
                $Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
                $UserAccount = Get-LocalUser -Name "Administrator"
                $UserAccount | Set-LocalUser -Password $Password
            }

        else
        {
            Write-Host($server + " is offline, nothing to do")
        }
                    
    }
}
```

I got this error when running the script:

```
<IP_Address> is online
New-PSSession : [<IP_Address>] Connecting to remote server <IP_Address> failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the 
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:12 char:31
+ ... rSessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential 'Administ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed
Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:22 char:37
+             Invoke-Command -Session $ServerSessions -ScriptBlock {
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
 
else : The term 'else' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.
At line:30 char:9
+         else
+         ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (else:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 

            Write-Host($server + " is offline, nothing to do")
```

If I use correct password, the script works fine.

**Update**

**Solution**

Below method works but I couldn't be able to handle catch statement with `catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]`. Instead I used `catch [Exception]`. It is not a good solution but it works fine for me now.

```
$servers = Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Scripts\TestServers.txt"
    
    foreach($server in $servers)
    {
        $pingtest = Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
        if($pingtest)
        {
            Write-Host($server + " is online")
            $Creds = Get-Credential 'Administrator'
            do{
                try
                {
                    $ServerSessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $Creds -ErrorAction Stop
                    Write-Host ("$ServerSessions")
                    
            
                }catch [Exception]
                {
                    Write-Host("Credential is incorrect! Try again")
                    $Creds = Get-Credential 'Administrator'
                }
            }while(!$ServerSessions)
    
            Invoke-Command -Session $ServerSessions -ScriptBlock {
                # Windows Server Versiyonunu check edip parolayı ona göre set etmek için
                Get-ComputerInfo | select WindowsProductName, WindowsVersion, OsHardwareAbstractionLayer
                $Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
                $UserAccount = Get-LocalUser -Name "Administrator"
                $UserAccount | Set-LocalUser -Password $Password
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Host($server + " is offline, nothing to do")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try/catch doesn't work if it is not a stopping error, so add the `-ErrorAction Stop` parameter to your session, and then wrap that try/catch inside a Do/While loop based on if you have a session or not and get new creds in the Catch part.

```
    $Creds = Get-Credentials 'Administrator'
    Do{
    try
    {
        $ServerSessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $Creds -ErrorAction Stop
        
    }catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]
    {
        Write-Host("Credential is incorrect! Try again")
        $Creds = Get-Credentials 'Administrator'
       
    }
    }While(!$ServerSessions)
```

Comment: May I suggest a `Remove-PSSession` in a `finally` block? Get's rid of those open connections. This is the route I wouldve taken as well; just because you can ping a computer, doesn't mean you can connect to it.

Comment: This is just trying to establish a connection. I don't think it is the right place to put a `Remove-PSSession` call. That would go later, after the `Invoke-Command` call.

Comment: Agreed, I just don't see why an `Invoke-Command` would have to be outside the `try` block. Anyways, just a suggestion.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I forgot to mention that, it worked but with a change. I don't understand why but `catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]` not working. It didn't catch the wrong password. I used `catch [Exception]`. It is not a good way but it is working for now. Any idea why `catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]` is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your curly braces for the `if` statement were incorrect. This is why properly indenting your code is of importance.

To retry the authentication, use a `while` loop that will keep looping until a new session is established. For example:

```
$servers = Get-Content "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Scripts\TestServers.txt"

foreach($server in $servers)
{
    $pingtest = Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    if($pingtest)
    {
        Write-Host "$server is online"
        while ($True) {
            try
            {
                $Cred = Get-Credential -UserName 'Administrator'
                $ServerSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $Cred
                break
        
            }catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]
            {
                Write-Host "Credential is incorrect! Try again"
            }
        }
        
        try {
            Invoke-Command -Session $ServerSession -ScriptBlock {
                # Windows Server Versiyonunu check edip parolayı ona göre set etmek için
                Get-ComputerInfo | select WindowsProductName, WindowsVersion, OsHardwareAbstractionLayer
                $Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
                $UserAccount = Get-LocalUser -Name "Administrator"
                $UserAccount | Set-LocalUser -Password $Password
        }
        finally {
            Remove-PSSession $ServerSession
        }

    }
    else {
        Write-Host "$server is offline, nothing to do"
    }
}
```

Comment: With Do while method, the re-prompt is working fine but I didn't understand why your method didn't work. It gives an error : `New-PSSession : [IP_Address>] Connecting to remote server <IP_Address>failed with the following error message : Access is denied. ......At line:13 char:35. I also add the `-ErrorAction Stop` to end of `New-PSSession` line but it is not working.

Comment: Probably because I only added that to the code and left the rest as is, while there are several issues with it (e.g. passing the string `Administrator` as a credential). I took care of those issues and updated the code now.